# Uart TxD & RxD voltage

Tags: gpio, uart

What's voltage of RPi pins 14 & 15 (RxD & TxD)?

I want to use an octocouplers, so I'm very interested in voltage parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Pi's gpios (which include the UART RXD, TXD gpios) are 0-3.3V.  A voltage outside that range will likely damage the gpio, how quickly will depend on how much current is allowed to flow.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: I've connected multimeter both to the ground and tx voltage and run an output.

Comment: @asiniy You'd be getting a PWM effect as the bits go high and low.  Just check TXD and ground when idle, i.e. not transmitting data (the default idle state is high).

Comment: @goldilocks ok, will try do that!

Comment: Yep, you're right, I get 3.16V with idle txd